# Cannot change font in NextUI NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, nextui

I am using Nextjs 14 with NextUi as the UI library. I have created the app using:
`npx create-next-app -e https://github.com/nextui-org/next-app-template`

However, when I change my fonts in font.ts, it still shows the same font regardless of what I change:

```
//font.ts
import { Montserrat as FontMono, Poppins as FontSans } from 'next/font/google';

export const fontSans = FontSans({
  weight: ['400', '500', '700'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-sans',
});

export const fontMono = FontMono({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-mono',
});
```

```
//layout.tsx
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import { siteConfig } from '@/config/site';
import { fontMono, fontSans } from '@/config/fonts';
import { Providers } from './providers';
import { Navbar } from '@/components/navbar';
import { Link } from '@nextui-org/link';
import clsx from 'clsx';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: {
    default: siteConfig.name,
    template: `%s - ${siteConfig.name}`,
  },
  description: siteConfig.description,
  themeColor: [
    { media: '(prefers-color-scheme: light)', color: 'white' },
    { media: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)', color: 'black' },
  ],
  icons: {
    icon: '/favicon.ico',
    shortcut: '/favicon-16x16.png',
    apple: '/apple-touch-icon.png',
  },
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head />
      <body
        className={clsx(
          'min-h-screen bg-background font-sans antialiased',
          fontSans.variable
        )}
      >
        <Providers themeProps={{ attribute: 'class', defaultTheme: 'dark' }}>
          <div className="relative flex flex-col h-screen">
            <Navbar />
            <main className="container items-center justify-center mx-auto max-w-7xl pt-16 px-6 flex-grow">
              {children}
            </main>
            <footer className="w-full flex items-center justify-center py-3">
              <Link
                isExternal
                className="flex items-center gap-1 text-current"
                href="https://nextui-docs-v2.vercel.app?utm_source=next-app-template"
                title="nextui.org homepage"
              >
                <span className="text-default-600">Footer</span>
                <p className="text-primary">Here</p>
              </Link>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Here, I tried to apply Poppins and Montserrat as the fonts, but the website shows the default font. Whatever font I use, it shows the default font only. Can anyone please help?

I tried using tailwind.config.js for changing the font family. That didn't work. Also tried global styles css. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `.variable` property of the generated fonts from the `next/font/google` module. This means to apply the fonts, you'd need to use the CSS variable in a `font-family` declaration. As per [the documentation for integrating with Tailwind CSS](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#with-tailwind-css), you'd need to have the following in your Tailwind configuration:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  // …
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--font-sans)'],
        mono: ['var(--font-mono)'],
      },
    },
  },
}
```